# Finding the indices of the rows where there are non-zero entries in a sparse csc_matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a numpy array, X:

```
type(X)
>>> <class 'scipy.sparse.csc.csc_matrix'>
```

I am interested in finding the indices of the rows where there are non-zero entries, in the 0th column.  I tried:

```
getcol =  X.getcol(0)
print getcol
```

which gives me:

```
(0, 0)  1
(2, 0)  1
(5, 0)  10
```

This is great, but what I want is a vector that has `0, 2, 5` in it.

How do I get the indices I'm looking for?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

With a CSC matrix you can do the following:

```
>>> import scipy.sparse as sps
>>> a = np.array([[1, 0, 0],
...               [0, 1, 0],
...               [1, 0, 1],
...               [0, 0, 1],
...               [0, 1, 0],
...               [1, 0, 1]])
>>> aa = sps.csc_matrix(a)
>>> aa.indices[aa.indptr[0]:aa.indptr[1]]
array([0, 2, 5])
>>> aa.indices[aa.indptr[1]:aa.indptr[2]]
array([1, 4])
>>> aa.indices[aa.indptr[2]:aa.indptr[3]]
array([2, 3, 5])
```

So `aa.indices[aa.indptr[col]:aa.indptr[col+1]]` should get you what you are after.

Comment: Yep. CSR and CSC matrices are stored as three arrays: `data`, `indices`, and `indptr`. The `indptr` array stores the offsets of each row/column into the `indices` array.

Comment: I see!  So, in this solution I need to give the `indptr` an integer value, which is the column number.  If I wanted to iterate over all the non-zero columns of my sparse matrix, would I do this with a standard `for` loop?  It feels strange to iterating over a sparse matrix for some reason.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the values in your non-zero columns? There is almost always a way to avoid the iteration, but it depends on exactly what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.